# How use Progress Circular

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-material

I have `<md-button>My button</md-button>` and want to use `<md-progress-circular>`, when I enter on the button, but content hasn't uploaded yet, so I want show on the button this spinner, but I don't know how :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic example of how to do this, you can either use ng-show or ng-if

```
<div ng-app='home'>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <md-button class="md-primary md-accent md-raised" ng-click="func()">
    My button<md-progress-circular ng-show="processing" md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>
  </md-button>
</div>
</div>
```

and this goes in your controller

```
$scope.func = function(){
  $scope.processing = true;
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.processing = false;
  },3000);
};
```

note that the $timeout is to simulate a promise or the time required to "upload content as you say"